# Need to pass runtime parameters using echo

Tags: echo

I have `test.exe` application which I run and it ask to enter password twice. In Unix I have seen this can be run using echo command for silent execution without editing the `test.exe`.

In Unix:

```
 echo -e "Password\nPassword"|test.ksh
```

Above command prompts for password twice and takes it through the echo command.

I want to do the same on DOS.

But I am getting a error like

```
 No console available for secure input 
 No console available for secure input 
 Can't spawn "cmd.exe": No such file or directory at / 
 Problem while processing the Password.
```

Comment: Do you have the source code for test.exe?

Answer (score 2):

```
(
  echo Password
  echo Password
) | test.exe
```

Comment: I tried that.. But it doesn't work too.. I guess it might be because of the password parameter.. I mean it is not visible from the console while we type. Also we cannot copy and paste password there.